# Como accedo a una propiedad de una coleccion en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

he llamado desde una vista el facade auth y he llamado la tabla pivot relpersonaperfil y me trae los datos correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y estos son los datos que muestra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
hasta ahi muy bien pero quiero acceder a un dato especifico de esa coleccion como lo es codperfil y lo hago de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me saca el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por que no pruebas haciendo un foreach para iterar el objeto $us y de esta manera ya poder acceder como en tu primer propuesta ya que lo que estas recibiendo es una colección

Comment: o también tratar así $us = Auth::user()->relpersonaperfil[0]->codperfil;

Comment: Hola lARAPRO, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.